# JQuery Hiding part of a form and avoiding browser autocompleting

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm using JQuery to hide part of a form and based on a question that has 2 radio buttons: "yes" mapped to 1 and "no" to 0, I make that part of the form appears so the user can fill it.

This is the part in charge of it. Sorry my JQuery sucks:

```
function appear(speed) {
    if ($("input[name='fillProfileNow']:checked").val() == "0") {
        $("#profileFields").hide(speed);
    }
    else {
        $("#profileFields").show(speed);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {         
    $("#profileFields").css("display","none"); 
    appear('');
});

$("input[name='fillProfileNow']").change(function() { appear('slow'); });
```

My problem is that I realized today testing my form, that Chrome uses form autocompletion based on my history to fill those hidden fields. The problem is the data that uses is crap as I sometimes don't always tell the truth, so a validation error happens, but it is not displayed as I haven't checked the radio button that renders that part of the form.

Is there any way to avoid this? maybe resetting fields if they are hidden? is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `autocomplete=off` to the inputs:

```
$("input[name='fillProfileNow']:checked").attr("autocomplete", "off").val()
```

Comment: Not sure what this does. I guess what this does is check the radio button if one of the hidden inputs is filled, right?

Comment: The `autocomplete=off` attribute tells the browsers not to use autocomplete on that field.

Answer (score 1):

And try setting the `defaultChecked` property to null:

```
$("input[name=fillProfileNow]").attr('defaultChecked', null);
```

or:

```
$("input[name=fillProfileNow]").each(function() { this.defaultChecked = null } );
```

Comment: By default there are 2 radio buttons fillProfileNow_0 and fillProfileNow_1 one for the answer "yes" and one for "no". Doing what you say doesn't fix the autocomplete problem, sorry.